# Run Clojure GraalVM native image on AWS Lambda custom runtime

Tags: clojure, aws-lambda, graalvm

Is there an easy way to deploy a Clojure application compiled with GraalVM `native-image` tool to AWS Lambda custom runtime?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Leiningen template](https://github.com/tokenmill/clojure-graalvm-aws-lambda-template) that could help with this problem.

Example:

```
lein new clojure-graalvm-aws-lambda your-lambda
cd your-lambda
make deploy-lambda-via-container
```

This example assumes that you have `make` and `Docker` installed in your system.

Note that the generated project is **not** a Leiningen project but a `tools-deps` project.

Comment: wow, this is some shameless self-promotion! you have even written this plugin days before asking the question.